# This action is invalid when the mock object is in replay state

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I'm converting MSUnit test to XUnit.

```
public class ClassName
{
    protected IDomainQueries MockILogQueries { get; private set; }
    protected IQueryContext MockQueryContext { get; private set; }

    public ClassName()
    {
        MockQueryContext = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IQueryContext>();
        MockILogQueries = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IDomainQueries>();
        //Getting error for the below line            
        MockQueryContext.Stub(r => r.LogQueries).Return(MockILogQueries);
    }
}
```

Above specified code is working in MSUnit but not in XUnit.

I'm getting the following error

```
Message:     System.InvalidOperationException : This action is invalid when the mock object is in replay state.
Stack Trace:
    ReplayMockState.GetLastMethodOptions[T]()
    RhinoMocksExtensions.Expect[T,R](T mock, Function`2 action)
    RhinoMocksExtensions.Stub[T,R](T mock, Function`2 action)
    ClassName.ctor() line
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does a mock object enter the replay state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932191/when-does-a-mock-object-enter-the-replay-state)

Comment: This error got resolved based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455729/xunit-rhinomocks-or-testdriven-net-issue